# Golden Layout Library - How do I access the controlsContainer of a specific component?

Tags: javascript, golden-layout

I have the following Layout:

```
myLayout = new GoldenLayout({
    content:[{
        type: 'row',
        content:[{
            type: 'component',
            componentName: 'testComponent',
            componentState: {},
            id:"Widget-1"
        },{
            type: 'component',
            componentName: 'testComponent',
            componentState: {}
        }]
    }]
});
```

How do I access the "controlsContainer" for the component with id="Widget-1".

I have tried using `myLayout.root.getItemsById("Widget-1").controlsContainer.prepend( DropDown );`

but I cant access it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, just loop through all items of the stack using

```
myLayout.on( 'stackCreated', function( stack ){}
```

Then target the correct item using its id.